# Inherited nav property EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
public abstract class Base {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public Related1 Related1 {get; set;}
    public Related2 Related2 { get; set; }
}

public class Concrete1: Base { }
public class Concrete2: Base { }

public class Related1 {
    public Concrete1 Concrete1 {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Concrete2> Concrete2s {get; set;}
}

public class Related2 {
    public ICollection<Concrete1> Concrete1s {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Concrete2> Concrete2s {get; set;}
}

//OnModelCreating
builder.Entity<Base>()
       .HasDiscriminator<byte>("type")
       .HasValue<Concrete1>(0)
       .HasValue<Concrete2>(1);

builder.Entity<Concrete1>()
       .HasOne(du => du.Related1)
       .WithOne(d => d.Concrete1)
       .HasForeignKey<Concrete1>(du => du.Related1Id);

 builder.Entity<Concrete1>()
        .HasOne(du => du.Related2)
        .WithMany(u => u.Concrete1s)
        .HasForeignKey(eu => eu.Related2Id);

builder.Entity<Concrete2>()
       .HasOne(du => du.Related1)
       .WithMany(d => d.Concrete2s)
       .HasForeignKey(du => du.Related1Id);

builder.Entity<Concrete2>()
       .HasOne(du => du.Related2)
       .WithMany(u => u.Concrete2)
       .HasForeignKey(eu => eu.Related2Id);

//...
public DbSet<Base> Bases { get; set; }
public DbSet<Concrete1> Concrete1s { get; set; }
public DbSet<Concrete2> Concrete2s { get; set; }
```

I've got error:

> The navigation property 'Concrete1' cannot be added to the entity type
>   'Related1' because its CLR type 'Concrete1' does not match the
>   expected CLR type 'Base'

How can it can be fixed? I have called HasDiscriminator() method, why does EF need Base CLR type as nav in Related1(2), not Concrete1(2)?

Comment: Have you tried declare the navigation property as virtual ?

Comment: @H. Herzl can it help really? there is EF Core

Comment: Please add `Related1Id` and `Related2Id` to your code.

Comment: How about `builder.Entity<Base>().Ignore(x => x.Related1)` and `builder.Entity<Base>().Ignore(x => x.Related2)`. I suspect your model is creating some surprise extra relations with an additional foreign keys because the navigation properties in Base are not sufficiently linked to key properties on the same level.

Comment: @grek40 I have implemented Ignore() on Base and have got the another error :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824437/ef-core-inherited-entities-has-navs-to-same-table